# replace all combinations of non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: php

I need to to create url from various strings.
So trying to replace all non-alphanumeric characters `and all of their combinations` - with a hyphen character (`-`)

```
$string = "blue - sky";
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '-', $string);
echo $string;
```

result - `blue---sky`
expected - `blue-sky`.

Comment: what about this: `"/[^a-z0-9]+/i"`

Comment: @bonaca the ["combinations"](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) part is missing from your `regex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `+` sign to replace more than one character with one replacement character:

```
string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/", '-', $string);
```

Comment: result is `blu - sky` (with spaces). How to remove spaces too, pls?

Comment: @bonaca removed the space (`9 `)which i copied from your code